# Modified Bessel function of second kind for imaginary order for small argument

Tags: taylor-expansion, bessel-functions

I would like to find an expression for the first terms in the expansion of the modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_n(z)$ for $n\in i\mathbb{R}$ and $z\in \mathbb{R}$ with $z\to 0^\pm$ (I am assuming such an expansion exists).

Is anyone aware of such formulas ? Most of what I could find is for real order only.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.45) for some formulas.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize that this is coming a bit late, but I thought I'd answer the question in case it helps others. According to the NIST Handbook of Special Functions, https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.45, for $x>0$ and $\nu>0$,

$$K_{i\nu}(x) = -\left( \frac{\pi}{\nu\sinh(\pi\nu)} \right)^{1/2} \sin\big( \nu\ln(\frac x 2)-\gamma_\nu \big) + \mathcal{O}(x^2).$$

$\gamma_\nu$ is defined by the equation

$$\Gamma(1+i\nu) = \left( \frac{\pi\nu}{\sinh(\pi\nu)} \right)^{1/2}e^{i\gamma_\nu},$$

where $\gamma_\nu$ is real and continuous with $\gamma_0=0.$